# Error: Element type is invalid:Edit button showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am new to react and am trying to put edit button next to the rows for edit function into the DB  However I am getting this error message.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `Department`.
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
D:/React/employee-app/src/components/Department.js:22
  19 |    fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/department')
  20 |    .then(response=>response.json())
  21 |    .then(data=>{
> 22 |     this.setState({deps:data});
     | ^  23 |    }
  24 |     );
  25 | }
View compiled
```

Here is the code:

```
Department.js

export class Department extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={deps:[],addModalShow:false,editModalShow:false}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    refreshList(){
       fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/department')
       .then(response=>response.json())
       .then(data=>{
        this.setState({deps:data});
       }
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

render(){
    const {deps,depid,depname} = this.state;
    let addModalClose = () => this.setState({addModalShow:false});
    let editModalClose = () => this.setState({editModalShow:false});
    return(
        <div>
        <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DepartmentId</th>
                    <th>DepartmentName</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {deps.map(dep =>
                <tr key = {dep.DepartmentID}>
                <td>{dep.DepartmentID}</td>
                <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                <td>
               <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button
                className="mr-2"
                 variant="info"
                onClick={()=>
                     this.setState({editModalShow:true,depid:dep.DepartmentID,depname:dep.DepartmentName})
                }>
                 Edit
                </Button>

                <EditDepModal
                show={this.state.editModalShow}
                onHide={editModalClose}
                depid = {depid}
                depname={depname}
                  />
               </ButtonToolbar>


                </td>
                </tr>
                
                )}
            </tbody>
            </Table>
            <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button 
                variant='primary'
                onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalShow:true})}>
                 Add Department
                </Button>
                <AddDepModal
                show={this.state.addModalShow}
                onHide={addModalClose}/>
            </ButtonToolbar>
            </div>
    )

}

}

export default Department;
```

This is the editmodaldep.js

```
export class EditDepModal extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {sanackbaropen: false, snackbarmsg:''};

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    snackbarClose = (event) =>{
        this.setState({snackbaropen:false});
      };
      handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/Department',{
        
        method:'PUT',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'

        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          DepartmentID:event.target.DepartmentID.value,
          DepartmentName: event.target.DepartmentName.value
        })
      })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then((result)=>
        {
          //alert(result);
          this.setState({snackbaropen:true,snackbarmsg:result})
        },
        (error)=>{
         // alert('Failed')
         this.setState({snackbaropen:true,snackbarmsg:'failed'})
      
        })

        }  
        render(){
            return(
              <div className="container">
                <Snackbar
                anchorOrigin={{vertical:"center",horizontal:'center'}}
                open ={this.state.snackbaropen}
                autoHideDuration = {3000}
                onClose={this.snackbarClose}
                message = {<span id= "message-id">{this.state.snackbarmsg}</span>}
                action={[
                  <IconButton
                  key="close"
                  aria-label="Close"
                  color="inherit"
                  onClick={this.snackbarClose}
                  >
                    X
                  </IconButton>
                ]}    />
        
               
                <Modal
              {...this.props}
              size="lg"
              aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
              centered
            >
              
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                  Edit Department
                </Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                
                            <Form.Group controlId="DepartmentID">
                                  <Form.Label>DepartmentID</Form.Label>
                                  <Form.Control
                                      type = "text"
                                      name="DepartmentID"
                                      required
                                      disabled
                                      defaultValue = {this.props.depid}
                                      placeholder="DepartmentID"
                                      />
                                </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="DepartmentName">
                                  <Form.Label>Department Name</Form.Label>
                                  <Form.Control
                                      type = "text"
                                      name="DepartmentName"
                                      required
                                      placeholder="Department Name"
                                      defaultValue = {this.props.depname}
                                      />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group>
                                  <Button variant="primary" type ="submit">
                                      Update Department
                                  </Button>
                              </Form.Group>
                            </Form>
                        </Col>
                        </Row>
               
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant= "danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </div>
            );
        }

       }

       export default EditDepModal;
```

I do not really understand this error. I have given export default to all the components in the solution.

Could someone please help in this?

Comment: Add this `this.refreshList = this.refreshList.bind(this);` in `Department.js` `constructor()`.

Comment: No its not working

Comment: `refreshList() { const that = this; fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/department').then(response=>response.json()).then(data => that.setState({deps:data}));}` try to set `this` to function variable, then use it to setState.

Comment: No still the same problem, this is a normal fetch function it was not showing error before?

Comment: Dept id is long in the web api is that the problem?

Comment: `console.log(data)` in `refreshList`. Looks like you try to set `undefined` to `array`.

Comment: do you want me to console.log the data?

Comment: Yes, you have to debug, what data is returned from api server.

Comment: its not showing any data when I do console.log

Comment: In that case, you can try to do this `.... then(data => that.setState({deps:data || []}));`

Comment: You want me to pass this and see?

Comment: This will set empty array to deps if there is no data returned from fetch. Yes try on your code and check if error is solved.

Comment: No same error just the error line has changed

Comment: show me the new error message

Comment: Check the render method of `Department`.
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
D:/React/employee-app/src/components/Department.js:21
  18 | 
  19 |    refreshList(){
  20 |       const that =this;
> 21 |       fetch('https://localhost:44363/api/department')
     | ^  22 |       .then(response=>response.json())
  23 |       .then(data => that.setState({deps:data || []}));
  24 |

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Show how you import components in both components. You have stripped everything before class ....

Comment: ok I will put it in an answer

Comment: Hi @Janiis. I have put it in the answer

Comment: It is better to edit question. Don't add code to answer, because it will mislead the users in future. I suggest you to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove keyword `export` from first line of your both components. Use just default export in the bottom of the file.

```
class Department extends Component{
 ....
 render() {
 }

}

export default Department;
```

And then for imports use this type of `import EditDepModal from './EditDepModal';`

You can read more about the difference between default and named imports in JS.

https://medium.com/@tharakabimal/understand-the-difference-between-default-and-named-imports-and-exports-fc04b2736c1a

Comment: what do you mean by use just default export that should stay as it is right?The bottom export default

Comment: Yes, remove keyword `export` where you declare your class component and the update `imports` with removing `{ }` because when you use default export, you import whole component with `import ComponentName from './ComponentName';`.

Comment: It worked thanks, could you just explain what was the issue

Comment: The issue was with components exports- you cannot use both named and default export of the same component. You have to use one. I usually use default export for class components. If the issue is solved, please mark answer as accepted - tick on green :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if your project setup has strict eslint rules and your changes are committed due to missing ; at statement:
this.state={deps:[],addModalShow:false,editModalShow:false}

Comment: What do you mean by that?